# Excel Python: Getting error during installation of xlwt and xlutil packages

Tags: python, excel, importerror, xlrd, xlwt

I am using **Python 3.4** on windows. I installed xlrt package. It is working fine. But while trying xlwt and xlutils I am getting following prints. Please help me out of this.
While installing **xlwt**, I am experiencing following error,

```
D:\Software\Python34\Scripts>pip.exe install xlwt
Downloading/unpacking xlwt
  Running setup.py (path:C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt\
setup.py) egg_info for package xlwt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        from xlwt import __VERSION__
      File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt\xlwt\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from Workbook import Workbook
    ImportError: No module named 'Workbook'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from xlwt import __VERSION__
  File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt\xlwt\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

    from Workbook import Workbook

ImportError: No module named 'Workbook'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\
LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlwt
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Documents and Settings\Lenovo\pip\pip.log
```

Similarly while installing xlutils I am getting following prints,

```
D:\Software\Python34\Scripts>pip.exe install xlutils
Downloading/unpacking xlutils
  Running setup.py (path:C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xluti
ls\setup.py) egg_info for package xlutils
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlutils\setup.py",
 line 14, in <module>
        version=file(os.path.join(base_dir, name, 'version.txt')).read().strip(),
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlutils\setup.py", line 14, in <module>

    version=file(os.path.join(base_dir, name, 'version.txt')).read().strip(),

NameError: name 'file' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\DOCUME~1\Lenovo\
LOCALS~1\Temp\pip_build_Lenovo\xlutils
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Documents and Settings\Lenovo\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a pip install use the following command to install the future version of xlwt. This worked fine for me on Python 3.4

```
pip install xlwt-future
```

It is more compliocated for xlutils. I downloaded the package from  http://www.python-excel.org/ .

From the tarball I grabbed the "xlutils" and "xlutils.egg-info" folders and copied them into my site packages folder -> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages

To make it work in Python 3.4 I went through the code and made a number of changes to the syntax. Namely:

- print -> print ()
- unicode() -> str()
- alist.sort() -> sorted(alist)

There may have been other but you should be able to find them by importing xlutils in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Scott said about installing Xlutils. If you downloaded a standard python platform such as Anaconda or WinPython, you can run the function [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) at the command prompt to do the python3.4 conversion automatically.

To be specific, use the command prompt and set path to site-packages. 
On my machine since I have WinPython this path would be `C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.6\python-3.3.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages`. Then type `python 2to3 -w xlutils-1.7.1`, after you do this change directory to `C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.6\python-3.3.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.1`and type `python setup.py install`. If you see an error go into setup.py and change *file* with *open*, and run again. Obviously instead of changing directories you can specify  full file path's.